# How to Set the value of Server Side Variable or ViewState value from JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to Validate control by JQuery, i can Valid them and its working Perfectly. I want to Stop the execution of Server Side code when the button is clicked. By Button Click Event Controls are Validated by JQuery and on same button some Operation is performed on Server Side. I want to set the viewstate value false, when validation error occurs from JQuery. My Question is that how to Set the Value of ViewState from Jquery.

Below is my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                           var value = $('#txtName').val().trim();
                            if (value == '') {
                                alert('Name Requried');
            //Here i Want to Set my ViewState Value to False, which will by Used on Server Side.. 
                                return;
                                }
                            });
```

If it possible...??? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: what is ViewState here actually ??

Comment: Here I have not Used ViewState, but before Return, I want to set viewstate value to False..

Comment: It's not very clear what the question here is. You do realize that by the time the user pushes the button the script that generates the page has already been completely executed long time ago?

Comment: You cannot change ViewState client-side. For one thing it's encrypted and for another, any changes will create a MAC viewstate error when the page posts back. The best that you can do is add a hidden element with the runat=server attribute and pass the value that you want to change server-side, changing it there.

Answer (score 0):

if your viewstate name is like this:

```
ViewState["code"] = "EE"
```

then you can write like this:

```
document.getElementById("vCode").InnerHTML='false';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can not do it client side. You've to do it server side if you want.

Alternate way would be to use HiddenField with runat="server". You can assign value at client side and it will be available to you in server side.